# How to handle SSL certificates for a CNAME pointing to a different domain name

Tags: apache-2.4, domain, ssl-certificate, subdomain, cname-record

**My goal is:**

```
*a.example1.com* should point to *example2.com/test*
```

**Data**:

- The hosting machine for example2.com has the SSL certificate  (wildcard) *.example2.com
- I manage both domains.

**Solutions I thought of:**

- Creating a subdomain *test.example2.com* pointing to content under '/var/www/site/test'. (subdomain should point to the same machine)
- Create a CNAME record as such: 
  *a.example1.com* CNAME *test.example2.com*

**Problem:**

This will cause an SSL certificate issue on the browser.
So, I need to install the SSL certificate for *a.example1.com* on the host machine for *example2.com* and more precisely on the virtual host *test.example2.com*.
However, I am not sure this is even possible?
I found this source on how to have two virtual hosts in apache with two different domains and therefore with different SSL certificates:
So If I do the following:

- Create a virtual host for *test.example2.com* --> pointing to '/var/www/site/news' and having the wildcard certificate '*.example2.com'
- Create another virtual host for *a.example1.com* --->pointing to /var/www/site/test and having the wildcard certificate 'a.example1.com' (on the same machine)
- And Created the following record:

  *a.example1.com* CNAME to *test.example2.com*

Would that solve my problem?

Comment: You can't CNAME to a URL like `/test` anyways. Why do you want to CNAME instead of having two A records and two virtualhosts?

Comment: The web server doesn't know whether you were using `A` or `CNAME` (however, if you need `MX` etc. for mail, you'd definitely want to use `A`). On the webserver you could a) enable SNI and get certificate for both domains b) get a multidomain certificate c) redirect both from HTTP to HTTPS on the one that already has certificate, possibly to a different subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

From your DNS example, you would have:

```
test.example2.com IN A 1.2.3.4
a.example1.com IN CNAME teste.example2.com
```

This basically means that your client will resolve a.example1.com to the ip `1.2.3.4`.
It also means that your web-server on `1.2.3.4` ( as you said, Apache ) will receive requests for both URLs, and Apache is smart enough to send the GET/POST etc., to the right place.

With segregation in your virtual hosts entry's (can even be on the same file), you can handle a lot of different URLs and domains.  I particularly have more then 200 vhosts files ( not that smart ) on one single Apache (moving to HAproxy due performance issues). So yes, having two completely different URLs on the same server would definitely work. Just watch out for proper TLS configuration ( like using the right key and cert, etc ).

[]`s